# django, python why timestamp changes after localize

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, pytz

**CODE:**

```
import pytz
from django.utils import timezone

KST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Seoul')
UTC = pytz.timezone('UTC')

default_time = timezone.datetime(2021, 11, 29, 16, 44)

current_manual_kst = KST.localize(default_time)
current_manual_utc = default_time
print(current_manual_kst.timestamp())
print(current_manual_utc.timestamp())
```

**RESULT:**

```
>>> 1638171840.0
>>> 1638204240.0
```

So, I can see that results are different.

I thought timestamps should be the same but results are not.

Why this happened?
And How to get the same timestamps (by default: UTC) from KST.localized datetime?

Comment: I don't see your code setting `default_time`'s tzinfo to UTC anywhere in your code, so `default_time` will be naive, thus considered local time, whatever that is - therefore, Unix time does not necessarily have to agree. Try with `current_manual_utc = default_time.replace(tzinfo=UTC)` instead. Yes, it is safe to use `replace` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `timestamp` is expressed in UNIX time, which is the number of seconds since midnight January 1st 1970 UTC. In order to convert a `datetime` to such a UNIX timestamp, that `datetime` needs to be interpreted as *some* timezone. Because you can't express it relative to 1970 UTC without defining what timezone it's in. So if you have a naïve `datetime` object (without timezone) and take its `timestamp()`, **it is interpreted as being in your local timezone** and is converted to UTC from there.

And 16:44 in Seoul is apparently a different time than 16:44 in your computer's "local" timezone.